# Substracting rasters with a "buffer" to ignore slight offset?

Tags: arcgis-pro, raster-calculator, differences, historical-maps

I would like your help to understand my problem and formulate the appropriate question about it.

- I have two maps of the same place at two different years, one from
  1900, other from 1957 (British Ordnance Survey sheets from Malta - non standard methodology). The latter has some revisions, and I would like to
  visualize the larger revisions with a difference raster.
- Maps have the same extent, but because they are drawn by hand, there
  are some random differences between them on some small details. In addition, there is possibly some subtle differences in their extent/proportions again due to hand drawing.
- I georeferenced them both using their 4 map neat lines corners, and a vector grid as the framework as shown in Figure 1 below. I have manually input the
  exact same map coordinates (coordinates of the vector corner), but source points can vary
  slightly because map neat lines differ slightly, so source
  pixel selection is visual/arbitrary.

**Figure 1.** *Vector grid (red line) and maps neat lines used for georeferencing. Black=1900, Red=1957*
[image: Figure 1. Vector grid (red line) and maps neat lines used for georeferencing. Black=1900, Red=1957]

---

I end up with the two rasters being aligned quite well (less than 1m offset at real scale) as seen below in Figure 2.

**Figure 2.** *Overlay of the two map rasters. Black: 1900, red: 1957*
[image: Figure 2. Black: 1900, red: 1957]

They are RGB rasters. So I have tried to reclassify them after categorizing values into 0 and 1, and then using the raster calculator to substract one from the other (1957 - 1900), as seen below in Figure 3. Of course, the result is not satisfactory because of the slight offset.

The type of result I want to retain is the **large orange block** at the left of "136" in Figure 3 below, or the **dashed purple curved line** near the bottom right corner. On the other hand, the results I'd like to avoid is all these orange and purple lines that should be overlapping precisely, and then show up as "0" in the difference map.

**Figure 3.** *Difference raster obtained with raster calculator (1957 - 1900). purple=-1, orange=1, transparent=0*
[image: Figure 3. Difference raster obtained from raster calculator (1957 - 1900). purple = -1, orange = 1]

Nonetheless, this is very close to the result I would like to have, **if only I could include cells that are more than 1 meter apart between the two rasters**, let's say. So to use some sort of "buffer" for my raster calculation. This is where I struggle to find the good keywords to research which functions could be adapted to this approach.

Does anyone have a lead, maybe a critique on my approach?

I might be tackling this issue from a wrong angle, given that the two rasters are almost impossible to perfectly align in the first place (given the hand drawn aspect).

Comment: Do you have an Advanced License?  If so, you could try 'Raster to Polygon' then 'Buffer' on each raster, then pass those two feature classes to 'Symmetrical Difference' or 'Erase'.  If you don't have Advanced, you could still try using 'Union' on those two feature classes, and then using definition query to remove any polygon where either of the union FIDs = -1.

Comment: I tried vectorization to polygons but the quality of the scan and the type of drawing generate unusable polygon for buffering. Some polygons are very wide, such as the whole contour of the map defined as "one polygon", they overlap, etc. Too much work to clean the resulting vector layer, unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe you could run 'Focal Statistics' on your difference raster, and experiment with the neighborhood and statistic combo that allows you to tease out the desired areas? Maybe find areas where the mean != 0 but range = 0, suggesting the entire neighborhood is either -1 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution found was to:

1. Improve the georeferencing to maximize overlap between the two time series. This was achieved by using map features which have been exactly preserved between the 2 series, such as the toponyms, with extra control points and 3rd-order transformation algorithm (or spline).
2. Produce a difference map as explained in OP
3. Smooth out the difference map using the "Focal statistics" tool as proposed by Brennan, with the "mean" statistics and a cell range around 5-8 to keep an acceptable resolution.
4. Change the symbology of the focal statistics raster to "classify" and adjust the class ranges to exclude or include required cell values on both ends. The middle class can have its transparency adjusted if required as well.

Here is an illustration of the result, using the same location but a larger map extent. The "large orange block" discussed in OP can be seen in black on the top left corner of the image.

[image]